# Libraries to recognize humans on photos/videos?

Tags: image-recognition

Are there any libraries around that can help me recognize human bodies (not only faces) on images?

Comment: What is your define of *recognize*? Distinguish them from monkeys, or identify them individually? We also miss the programming language you need them for. Please [read this](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) and [edit] your question.

Comment: Must these libraries be free (if so, add the tag:gratis] tag), or do you have a budget? Are they for any particular CPU, or o/s, or for web programming?

Comment: Please answer the questions then ask us to reopen, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) includes mechanisms that can be used to detect people in a view as in https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/11/09/pedestrian-detection-opencv/ it is:

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- A set of C++ libraries & Bindings
- Cross Platform